# How to compare a return value of a recursive function with an integer (actual parameter of function)

Tags: python, recursion, jython-2.7

I need to compare the return value of a recursive function with an integer.
Doing recursively the sum of all elements of a list , I have to compare the final sum with an integer "n" giving back TRUE if sum == n , FALSE if sum != n . In addiction to the function have to return FALSE if i'm giving an empty list . 
Here I report the code to clarify the situation :)

```
def function(list_of_numbers,int):

   if not list:

     return false # I have to return false if list is empty.

   if len(l) > 0:

     return l[0] + function(list_of_numbers[1:],int) # recursive sum of element

   # and here i'm stuck !
```

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: I'm confused. What is your function supposed to return? The sum of some ints? Or a boolean value?

Comment: I think you should use two functions. The function ends once a return statement is reached, so the function would just return the sum.

Comment: `l`, `list`, `list_of_numbers`; which one is it? And what is `int` supposed to be/do? Please provide runnable code.

Comment: You shouldn't let a (recursive) function return two types of values (see Kevin's comment). You could return both though, a bool and an integer. If this is an assignment ("function have to return FALSE if i'm giving an empty list" and "compare the return value of a recursive function with an integer."), that seems an odd fit, to have a function either return False or an integer. Better raise some Exception if an empty listed is given as argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when `not l` we either got passed an empty list or have reached our base case so compare `n` to our `test` number, if you want an empty list to return True change `test=-1` to `test=0` :

```
def function(l, n=0, test=-1):
    if not l:
        return n == test
    else:
        n += l[0]
        return function(l[1:], n, test)


In [2]: function([1,2,3],test=6)
Out[2]: True

In [3]: function([1,2,3],test=5)
Out[3]: False

In [4]: function([1,2,3])
Out[4]: False

In [5]: function([])
Out[5]: False
```

If you want an empty list to return False you can check how many times the function has been called and either compare n to test or return False :

```
def function(l, n=0, test=0, calls=0):
    if not l:
        return n == test if calls > 0 else False
    else:
        n += l[0]
        calls += 1
        return function(l[1:], n, test,calls)
```

If you just want to pass a single argument the number to test against:

```
def function(l, test, n=0, calls=0):
    if not l and calls == 0: # changed for jython
        return False
    if not l:
        return n == test 
    else:
        n += l[0]
        calls += 1
        return function(l[1:],test,n, calls)
```

Comment: I had an idea similar to this, except it only had two arguments. The one line version being: `function = lambda l, value: value == 0 if not l else function(l[1:], value-l[0])`

Comment: `function([], test=0)` returns True, which seems to be contradictory with the requirements.

Comment: @njzk2,  there are different ways of interpreting the question, I would not put much heed in the OP's code considering it would  not even run but I added  a case to handle when a list is empty and have it return False

Comment: @Kevin, probably a nicer implementation than mine for a straight forward implementation

Comment: to clarify : if I call my function like this --> function([1,2,3],6) this must return TRUE (1+2+3 = 6 , 6 = 6)  function([1,2,3],5) this must return FALSE (1+2+3 = 6 , 5 != 6)         function([],4) this must return FALSE (list is empty)

Comment: @RobertoPavia, that is what the function does

Comment: @PadraicCunningham But I need to give only 2 parameter to my function like --> function(list,int) (this exercise has to be done without using test or calls variables)

Comment: @RobertoPavia, the last example uses only two arguments, you don't have to pass anything else

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Forgive me for stubbornness but i'm writing this code in JES (jython) and it doesn't work ! There is a problem with " return n == test if calls > 0 else False " . I think syntax problem

Comment: @PadraicCunningham ok! now works ! I'm gonna try it again to understand better .. Thanks Friend :)

Comment: no worries, add some print statements and it will make it easier to understand what is happening

Comment: can you please explain what "return something == something else"? is something I never seen before

Comment: it is just using the comparative operator, it will return True or False based on whether the elements are equal or not

Comment: It was a plasure , i've learn more with you than with my professor .. thanks man :)